# Как получить последнии записи в SQL таблице?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Всем привет!

Использую в CI следующий запрос:

```
function get_log_transactions($username) 
{
    return $this->db->where("sender", $username)->limit(20)->get("transactions");
}
```

Получаю 20 записей из нужной таблицы. Как сделать так, чтобы выдавались последние 20 записей, а не первые?

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?18

Comment: $this->db->order_by('title', 'DESC'); https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results

Comment: будет выглядеть примерно так `$this->db->where("sender", $username)->order_by('title', 'DESC')->limit(20)->get("transactions")` title только поменяйте на нужное поле.

Comment: Все работает - оформите ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данной цели используем метод

```
 $this->db->order_by('transactions', 'DESC');
```

Выглядеть будет примерно так

```
$this->db->where("sender", $username)->order_by('transactions', 'DESC')->limit(20)->get("transactions")
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results)